# jQuery object info retrieval issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have an object with some details nested in the object (assume any level) and I want to retrieve the data and then store it in a new object. See my sample. I am not getting what I expected. Can anyone give me the best way to get retrieved the object?

object:

```
var myObj = {
        info:[
            [
                [
                    {'name':'first Name'},
                    {'name' : 'Second Name'}
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
```

My function to retrieve and get the new object (it is not working properly):

```
   var getIt = function (data){
        $.map(data, function (val,num){
            var myObj = {};
            if(typeof val === 'object'){
                getIt(val);
            }else{
                myObj = val // as well this is wrong, only last data i am getting.
            }
            console.log(myObj);
            return myObj;
        })

    }
    var x = getIt(myObj);
    console.log(x);//i am not get any result. i need the result like this x= {{name:first name},{name:'second name'}}
```

Comment: So you want all the objects inside an object, in an array?

Comment: my main requirement is, peeling out the data from nested object or array. in my console comments i given details.

Comment: Tip: Don't use jQuery for things like this. Write a plain JS loop. Or use a library that is made for data processing, like underscore.